# Background mode plugin on Ionic 3: splashscreen keeps showing when exit app and open it again

Tags: ionic3

I'm currently developing an Ionic 3 application, I'm having troubles with background mode plugin, this is the code I have on my app.component.ts constructor:

```
  this.backgroundMode.enable();
  this.backgroundMode.overrideBackButton();

  if(this.backgroundMode.isActive()){
    let alert = this.alert.createAlert('¡BG!', '');
    alert.present();
  }
```

I'm showing an alert if background mode is active and it shows that alert, but splashscreen keeps showing. Am I doing something wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

According to its Document, it dosnt guarantee to keep your app in rom memory. But your some service or tread will keep open during your app is close.

I solved this problem by add "platform.registerBackButtonAction" to main page. It minimize app without clean from memory if user press android back button.

Also i removed splash plugin and replaced   with a white image with centered logo. 
I reduced app launch time to 2.5 sec. And i have  wish on future of ionic versions to boost app start time.